# IDE for programming in metalanguage?

Tags: ide, metalanguage

I've recently started learning metalanguage. Is there a jetbrains IDE for it? If not, which is the best IDE for metalanguage programming. Doesn't have to be open source. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nah, JetBrains doesn't have an IDE for ML. Look here: http://www.jetbrains.com/products.html

In fact, most Standard ML / OCaml developers prefer to use a straight text editor like emacs. But if you're willing to check out F# (and on Windows), you can use Visual Studio :)

http://fsharp.org/use/windows/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give both a try :)
I actually checked out their products. Was a  bit confused about whether MPS http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/ could be used.